# Why does TortoiseGit "Edit conflicts" show all lines as conflicted

Tags: git, tortoisegit, git-merge-conflict

When rebasing my feature branch on the current state of origin/master, Git notified me of conflics:

```
CONFLICT (directory/file): There is a directory with name modules/mod_name/shared/miniball in HEAD. Adding modules/mod_name/shared/miniball as modules/mod_name/shared/miniball~Poly-PS+Poly-Approx Arbeitsstand 01.07.2018
Auto-merging modules/mod_name/mod_nameExt.h
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in modules/mod_name/mod_nameExt.h 
Auto-merging modules/mod_name/mod_name.vcxproj
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in modules/mod_name/mod_name.vcxproj
Auto-merging modules/mod_name/mod_name.h
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in modules/mod_name/mod_name.h
Auto-merging modules/mod_name/mod_name.cpp
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in modules/mod_name/mod_name.cpp
Auto-merging modules/mod_name/ModuleVersion.h
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in modules/mod_name/ModuleVersion.h
Auto-merging modules/mod_name/Intern/pgen.h
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in modules/mod_name/Intern/pgen.h
Auto-merging modules/mod_name/Intern/pgen.cpp
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in modules/mod_name/Intern/pgen.cpp
Auto-merging modules/mod_name/Intern/ChainGenerator.h
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in modules/mod_name/Intern/ChainGenerator.h
Auto-merging modules/mod_name/Intern/ChainGenerator.cpp
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in modules/mod_name/Intern/ChainGenerator.cpp
Patch failed at 0008 Poly-PS+Poly-Approx Arbeitsstand 01.07.2018
The copy of the patch that failed is found in: .git/rebase-apply/patch

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
```

When opening the file `chaingenerator.cpp` with the TortoiseGit edit conflicts dialog, it shows every line of the file as conflicted, even those that are clearly similar.

[image: TortoiseGit edit conflicts]

The workflow up to the rebase was approximately the following

```
git checkout master
git branch Dev_PolyApproxIntegration
git checkout Dev_PolyApproxIntegration

... <Editing&Commiting in Dev_PolyApproxIntegration> ...
... <Somebody pushing commits into master>

git branch Dev_PolyApproxIntegration_Rebase29_01
git checkout Dev_PolyApproxIntegration_Rebase29_01
git pull origin master
git rebase master
```

I don't understand why Git is unable to process the (expected) conflicts that might have risen from somebodies commits into master. 
I've created a temporary branch (...rebase29_01) because in the past, I've been burned by the very same procedure (and errors), and wished to have a "known good" branch to return to if things fail. 
Otherwise, my commands should have been pretty much textbook stuff IMHO. Is there any issue with the way I've performed the workflow? Was it somebodies commits who broke things for me? I've got not idea what they did.

Also, how do I go from here? Manually merging every difference in the files is an impossibility.

Comment: Looks like a line endings problem (maybe check `core.autocrlf` setting)

Comment: The option `AutoCrlf` is enabled in the TortoiseGit settings, and `git config --get core.autocrlf` returns `true`. Is this correct?

Comment: I've dug into this, and apparently it is a 3-way-merge where both local and remote use windows-style line endings. base uses linux-style but appears to be completely empty

Comment: Same problem here!

Answer (score 0):

Just found out what the problem is. The merge tool is showing the conflicts based on conflict markers put there by git merge.

Comment: Interesting. But how does one clean up such situations? If you can offer a strategy here I'd gladly accept the answer, even though the problem has since been dealt with (by manual merge ... ewwww)

Comment: @antipattern That is my problem right now. For some reason that I don't know git is marking whole the file as conflict though only a few lines are different. And it is not because of line endings.